# running a c# .net Console Application multiple time with different variables

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

I'm trying to automate a task. I have to repeat the task 14 times and want my application to do it for me. my application runs once without a problem. Can anyone explain how I do this without duplicating code?

My application scrapes html from a url and then saves it to a location on my computer. (the html is an email signature). I need the application to do this for 14 different people.

Example.

//person1

string urlAddress1 = "http://www.url.com/person1";

filestream 1 = @"C:\Users\ellio\Desktop\test\person1.htm

//person2

string urlAddress2 = "http://www.url.com/person2";

filestream 2 = @"C:\Users\ellio\Desktop\test\person2.htm

etc

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

namespace GetSignatureHtml
{

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string urlAddress = "http://www.url.com/person1";

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urlAddress);
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader readStream = null;

            if (response.CharacterSet == null)
            {
                readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream);
            }
            else
            {
                readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.GetEncoding(response.CharacterSet));
            }

            string data = readStream.ReadToEnd();

            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\ellio\Desktop\test\person1.htm", FileMode.Create))
            {
                using (StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(fs, Encoding.UTF8))
                {
                    w.WriteLine(data);
                }
            }

            Console.Write(data);
            Console.ReadKey(true);

            response.Close();
            readStream.Close();
        }
    }    

}
```

}

Comment: Create a method that takes in the url and output filename as arguments. Then call that method 14 times form the main method.

Comment: Use a loop, read person name from an array and append it to strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest passing an argument into the `Main` method which is a file containing all the URLs to fetch. You can then read all those URLs into a list or array (e.g. with `File.ReadAllLines`, and infer the output file from the URL. Move most of your current code into a method that just accepts the URL, so the code will look something like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (args.Length != 1)
        {
            // Display some error message here
            return;
        }

        string[] urls = File.ReadAllLines(args[0]);
        foreach (var url in urls)
        {
            DownloadUrl(url);
        }
    }

    private static void DownloadUrl(string url)
    {
        // Put most of your current code in here.
        // You need to infer the name of the file to save - 
        // consider using new Uri(url), then Uri.LocalPath
    }
}
```

Then you just need to put the URLs into a text file, and specify that when you run the code.

Note that this *could* all be done with just one URL per command line argument, but by the time you've got 14 URLs on a command line, it's going to be a bit painful to check. I tend to find that using a file for the data makes life easier.

As asides on the rest of the code, you should use a `using` statement for the response, and I'd encourage you to use `File.WriteAllText` as a simpler way of creating the file. You might want to look at using `HttpClient` as an alternative approach to the whole thing, although I'm not sure whether it applies the response encoding in the same way that you do.

Comment: It took a little bit of learning on my part, but your answer got me there. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Move your work into a method, then iterate over that method.

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

namespace GetSignatureHtml
{

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            foreach(arg in args)
            {
                FindData(arg.urlAddress);
            }
        }

        public void FindData(arg)  
        {
            string urlAddress = "http://www.url.com/person1";

            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urlAddress);
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                StreamReader readStream = null;

                if (response.CharacterSet == null)
                {
                    readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream);
                }
                else
                {
                    readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.GetEncoding(response.CharacterSet));
                }

                string data = readStream.ReadToEnd();

                using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\ellio\Desktop\test\person1.htm", FileMode.Create))
                {
                    using (StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(fs, Encoding.UTF8))
                    {
                        w.WriteLine(data);
                    }
                }

                Console.Write(data);
                Console.ReadKey(true);

                response.Close();
                readStream.Close();
            }
        }    
    }
}
```